# How to request REDRAW from Xamarin.forms' side SkiaSharp?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I'm making app with using Xamarin.forms.
I'm drawing 2d view with using SkiaSharp.

I'm able to use SetNeedDisplay on iOS pcl side to make animation.

But I want to call it from Forms pcl. 
Is there any method like that?

Comment: Sounds like you will need to use X.Forms Dependency Service. See: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/

Comment: @jgoldberger Yes. I could do it by using many other way including it. But I'm looking for easier way. (like made by skiasharp.forms side)

Comment: Take a look at the thread :  https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/82523/skiasharp-direct-drawing

Comment: @SushiHangover Hi Sushi, Thanks for many times. The link you gave me is little bit complicated. So I decided just using OnPropertyChanged(from forms) and call SetNeedsDisplay(on iOS) and Invalidate(on Android) each customrenderer. It works fine and easier for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SkiaSharp Views for Xamarin.Forms provides the `InvalidateSurface()` for this particular reason:

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKCanvasView.InvalidateSurface()/

and

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKGLView.InvalidateSurface()/

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for reply. Is this new thing? I have been using SkiaSharp on forms by using custom renderer, so it means that I didn't know there is any SkiaSharp's view for FORMS and no need to use custom renderer anymore?

Comment: I added this in a few months ago, but it is in a separate NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp.Views.Forms see in the release notes: https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/releases/

Comment: And you are right, no need for custom renderers - you can even use the GL views for hardware acceleration: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/SkiaSharp.Views.Forms/

Comment: OMG! Good job. Thanks so much. I'll add it right now.

Comment: I replaced all. It works great except the fact I had to put canvas.Scale(2) to make it same as previous Screen. Is this correct? I didn't have to set scale as 2. Perhaps scale 2 was default and now 1?

Comment: very weird. I have to set canvas.Scale(4) on Android to make it same with iOS. What's going on?

Comment: Hi Matthew, I checked updated sample and found a code to archive it, which is measuring scale with using e.Info.Width. And it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: One more question, the fact that you provide GLView is actually really cool. Is there any disadvantage using it? One I found is that "canvas.Clear(SKColors.Transparent);" does not work on SKGLView(on Android - works fine on iOS).

Comment: I haven't noticed a disadvantage yet, and I would even go so far as to say that it is probably the better option. About the transparency, could you create an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp. It should go transparent, but I may have missed setting that option. Transparency adds extra performance hits when rendering, but I don't think it will be noticeable for most cases.

Comment: I think you just created that issue :)

Comment: Yes I did. Thanks Matthew.